# Links in user's pages hidden

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

For example, see [Oddthinking](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/23/oddthinking)'s profile. In the about me section, try to guess where the links are. They are invisible unless you hover over them.

Comment: So tempted to remove all the links, just to make it more challenging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix will be pushed out in the next build, > rev 2012.4.10.2176.